# Swift Post method in AppDelegate to root ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire, appdelegate

I write the function with post method to pushing to the ViewController. In post method, I'm getting the type of the user, and by type, I should push to different ViewControllers

```
class GetUser:NSObject {
    class func restartapp() {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {return}
        var url = baseurl + "/get-user/"
        var param = ["token":APItoken.getToken()!]
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case.failure(let err):
                print(err)
            case.success(let val):
                var json = JSON(val)
                print(json)
                if json["user"]["role_id"].intValue == 2 {
                    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: DriverMainPage())
                }
                if json["user"]["role_id"].intValue == 1 {
                    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: MainPageController())
                }
            }
        }
        UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCurlDown, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

When i return this code in AppDelegate I get error NSException

Comment: please post exception.

Comment: you mention that `push to different ViewControllers` but in your code, you are reset root controller of main window

Answer (score 0):

Try to run success block on main thread, like

**Reset root controller:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if json["user"]["role_id"].intValue == 2 {
        window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: DriverMainPage())
    }
    if json["user"]["role_id"].intValue == 1 {
        window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: MainPageController())
    }
}
```

**Push on root controller:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   if json["user"]["role_id"].intValue == 2 {
        (window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(DriverMainPage(), animated: true)
   }
   if json["user"]["role_id"].intValue == 1 {
        (window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(MainPageController(), animated: true)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the method DriverMainPage()/MainPageController() returns instance of a UINavigationController or a UIViewController. These methods should return UIViewController Objects only.

If it returns instance of UINavigationController, you might be getting following exception.
   "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported' ".

Which means you are instantiating a UINavigationController with a instance of UINavigationController which is not allowed.

If it returns UIViewController instance, then please edit your question with Exception you are getting.

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException